# Unusual behaviour of "\r" character in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, char, escaping

I typed tried to use implement the backslash character '\r' in java code  by using the following statement on my IntelliJ Ide compiler

```
 System.out.print("This  message will self destruct in five seconds\r");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){

    }
    System.out.print("Bye");
```

The output which I got was as:

```
...five seconds and then on the same line "Bye"
```

But the expected output must have been as:

```
"This  message will self destruct in five seconds"...after five seconds on 
the beginning of the same line "Bye" only
```

But If I type the following the same code snippet as:

```
System.out.print("This  message will self destruct in five seconds");
try {
Thread.sleep(5000);
}
catch (InterruptedException e){

}
System.out.print("\rBye");
```

then I get the above mentioned desired output.Why is this happening I really have no clue...The very first code gives the output on https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler as:

```
This  message will self destruct in five seconds   
Bye
```

I am really confused please help.

Comment: Doesn't work in Intellij console for ages. It's a known issue

Comment: Looks like IntelliJ doesn't handle `\r` correctly and removes the whole line instead of just moving the cursor. The correct result is btw "Byes  message will self destruct in five seconds" and not just "Bye".